# Error in op-amp integrator due to delay in attaining second summing point constraint

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, integrator

An op-amp in negative feedback forces both inverting and non-inverting inputs to the same value. But this takes some time which as per my knowledge is few nanoseconds. So won't this time delay cause an error in the output of the op-amp integrator, as the formula for an integrator assumes that the inverting input is at 0V (as is the non-inverting one)? Are there any noticeable consequences of this delay when dealing with signals that change so fast, that the inputs aren't even at 0V?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error caused by limited speeds (slew rate)  will be orders of magnitude smaller than other  things, like input offset voltages and bias currents, and are usually ignored for model frequencies.  What "modest" is will be determined by the op amp and gain.

Comment: Not true at all - harmonic distortion is a problem with op-amps on high-speed signals and fast integrators. DC accumulating integrators may be OK but there are plenty of high speed integration circuits used in filters.

Comment: @Andyaka That's what the "modest frequency" part was trying to address.  I guess we pick which aspects of the real op amp we're going to address as an answer.  The question I envision from askers at this level is "Why is my integrator saturating and the rail when the input is zero?", which IMO is the first second order effect that the beginner is likely to encounter before bumping into GBW issues.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any noticeable consequences of this delay when dealing with
>   signals that change so fast, that the inputs aren't even at 0V?

This happens a lot and "the delay" is due, in main, to the open loop gain characteristic of the op-amp. Here's a "generic" op-amp curve courtesy of the internet: -

[image]

At DC the open loop gain is (say) 100 dB (100,000). This means that for a 1V output there is a real discrepancy between inverting and non-inverting inputs of 10 uV. Not much of course and usually a lot less than other errors.

At 1 kHz the gain has dropped to 60 dB (1,000) and for a 1V RMS sinewave on the output there is a very real input discrepancy of 1 mV RMS. It gets worse as you go up in frequency. For instance at 100 kHz the gain is 20 dB (10) and for 1 V RMS on the output the input discrepancy is 0.1 V RMS.

These are all "open-loop" figures and represent one of the many nuances exhibited by real op-amps in the real world.

The "closed-loop" consequences can be: -

- Lower gain than a simple analysis would predict
- Distortion of the output compared to the input (linear amplifier)
- General harmonic distortion i.e. not getting predictable signal output results (i.e. in an integrator
- Instability when the loop is closed (sometimes)

Answer (score 1):

The frequency response and the finite gain and sometimes slew rate cause errors.

Consider an inverting op-amp integrator hit with a step input u(t). The output will take some time to respond and will settle out approaching a ramp output of slope dvout/dt = -Vin/RC

Slew rate won't typically be a problem in this configuration, but the output will take some time to respond, and there will be a persistent error compared to the ideal slope of the integrator. Below is a simulation of an op-amp integrator with gain -0.0001 (100nF/1K) hit with a step -10V input at t = 100usec. As you can see the input is fed through the input resistor to the output until the op-amp catches up, it overshoots a tiny bit from a linear ramp (hard to see on the plot) then begins something like the ideal ramp, but with a slight persistent error. The op-amp is an LM324 type. After 1.5 or 2usec the output is fairly close to ideal.

[image]